# Taxonomies don't show up on in the dashboard page for a custom post type in wordpress 5.22

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

In wordpress 5.22 , After creating a custom post type like:

```
function create_products_cpt(){
    register_post_type( 'product',
        array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'thumbnail',
                'custom-fields'
            ),
            'taxonomies'=>['product-category'],
            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'register_metaboxes',
            'show_in_rest' => true
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy('product-category','product',array(
        'hierarchical'=>true,
        'label'=>'product categories'
    ));

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_products_cpt' );
```

I am able to create post types and categories inside the taxonomy from the dashboard, but it is impossible to mark a specific post of that post type as belonging to any of the categories, since the selector just doesn't appear.
I double-checked on an older version of wordpress (4.89) and it does work as intended, selector and all.
What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've pasted your code in Twenty Nineteen and it works as expected with Classic Editor ( and I'm sure it will work pre-Block Editor also ). Your taxonomy will not show up in the Block Editor unless you specify to display that taxonomy in rest as you've done with your post type:

```
register_taxonomy( 'product-category', 'product', array(
    'hierarchical'=>true,
    'label'=>'product categories',
    'show_in_rest' => true
) );
```

Once you enable REST it will become available in the Block Editor.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! I didn't realise that the new editor uses rest.
In general, I being more comfortable with the "classic" one, how do I switch back to it?

Comment: I'm glad that ended up working for you! If you found the answer helpful you can let future readers know by upvoting it by using the arrow above or if this ended up solving your issue you can click the checkmark to show your question has been answered. If you're looking to switch back to the old editor there's the supported [Classic Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) plugin which does it with ease.